# I need help on how to return certain values

Tags: php, html, database, return

Basically, I have a list of two columns on a spreadsheet, for example:

```
1HFG  3928
8HCN  9201
4NXZ  3303
0QWX  1882
```

What I want to do is have a text box (as a webpage, so will copy the data over, not as an excel sheet) where users can input something from the first column such as 1HFG and it will return 3928 and likewise for everything else.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: An excel macro will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

In html its a select tag and in php its an associative array.

html:

```
<select>
 <option value="3928"> 1HFG </option>
 <!--and so on-->
</select>
```

and you can get your value automaticly via selected item of select tag

php:

```
<?php
 $arr = [
  '1HFG' => '3928',
  /* and so on */
 ];
?>
```

and you can get your value by accessing it by key

Comment: Hi mate. I didn't want it from a dropdown box. I wanted it as user input.

For example, a user would input '1HFG' and if it matched, it would throw back '3928' in this example otherwise it would say 'Code not found'.

Comment: There are many way to do it. You can do an input field and in js by Enter you can read you value and check if it exists in your storage (it can be an array associative array ore something else) If not, show en error. Or you send you value to server via ajax and check it on server side. All implementation are the right choice. 
But in main view you need a value and a storage with values to check. What it would be its you to decide.